# Pointwise Convergence of Convolutions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normal-distribution, convolution, weak-convergence

While reading chapter 4 of "Deep Learning Architectures, A Mathematical Approach" by Ovidiu Calin, I stumbled upon the following statement:

> Using the fact that the Gaussian tends to Dirac measure, $\lim_{\sigma \to +0}G_\sigma(x) \to \delta(x)$, we have
> $$
> \lim_{\sigma \to +0} f_\sigma(x) = \lim_{\sigma \to +0} (f*G_\sigma)(x) = (f*\delta)(x) = f(x),
> $$

where $f(x)$ is an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $G_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$ and $f_\sigma(x) = (f*G_\sigma)(x) = \int f(u)G_\sigma(x-u)du$.

From what I know, I wasn't very sure about this result. Unfortunately, the proof is omitted from the book so I tried to verify the claim by myself. It is not exactly the same but I was able to confirm the results below by following argument in Chapter 9 of "Real and Complex Analysis" by Walter Rudin.

**Result 1:** If $f$ is bounded and continuous at point $x$, then
$$
\lim_{\sigma\to +0}f_\sigma(x) = f(x).
$$

**Result 2:** If $1\leq p < \infty$ and $f\in L^p$, then $f_\sigma$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ as $\sigma \to +0$.

From the second result, it follows that there exists a sequence $\sigma_n \to +0$ such that $f_{\sigma_n}(x) \to f(x)$ almost surely. But it does not extend to pointwise almost sure convergence of $f_\sigma \to f$.

It doesn't seem to be possible to show pointwise almost sure convergence $f_\sigma \to f$ without assumptions like in the result 1. But I'm not sure if there is something special about gaussian or if there is a counterexample to it.

I appreciate it if anyone could prove the claim or provide a counterexample to it. You don't have to write full solution, if you know a good reference, then just a reference is fine.

**Update:** As Jochen pointed out, by following the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581271/pointwise-a-e-convergence-of-convolution), we can show almost sure pointwise convergence if $f \in L^\infty$. So, the question really is whether we can relax it to $f \in L^1$.

Comment: The lack of pointwise convergence is partly due to the fact that $L^p$ functions do not have well-defined pointwise values...

Comment: I'm asking about this specific construction, where pointwise values are well defined through convolution.

Comment: Seeing things like $\lim\limits_{\sigma\to 0} G_\sigma(x) =\delta(x)$ -- which do not make sense pointwise -- I doubt that your source is reliable concerning subtle differences between different types of convergence. I don't know whether $G_\sigma\ast f\to f$ a.s. for every integrable $f$ but I guess that *Lebesgue's differentiation theorem* might help.

Comment: @Jochen I'm pretty sure the author wrote $\lim_{\sigma \to 0}G_\sigma(x) = \delta (x)$ intentionally informal here since they called $\delta (x)$ as "Dirac measure" not "Dirac function".

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581271/pointwise-a-e-convergence-of-convolution ? The assumptions slightly differ from yours but the main argument is indeed Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for the info! The difference is not actually slight but what we can confirm from the post is that as long as $f$ is bounded, almost sure pointwise convergence is guaranteed. So, now the point is really about whether we can relax the condition to $f \in L^1$

Comment: The comment to the answer of the linked question suggests what is needed additionally for $f\in L^1$ instead of $L^\infty$. For the Gaussian convolution this shoud not be a problem. The key ingredient in the proof, Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, holds for $L^1$-functions.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, I read that comment. But, it is just a suggestion and if you actually do the detail, you'll see it is not that trivial to relax the assumption to $L^1$.

Comment: This follows from Theorem 8.15 in Folland's "Real Analysis" book (2nd edition).

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks very much for providing me with a great reference!

Answer (score 0):

(Not exactly an answer, but too long for a comment)

If you only require $f$ to be integrable, the pointwise convergence fails on $\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]$ for arbitrary real numbers $a<b$.

Indeed, because we have $\int G_\sigma(x-u)du = 1$, we can write for all $\sigma>0$

$$ \begin{align*}
f_\sigma(x) - f(x) &= \int_{\mathbb R} \left[f(u) - f(x)\right]G_\sigma(x-u)\ du\\
&:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}  \int_{\mathbb R} \left[f(u) - f(x)\right]\exp\left(-\frac{(x-u)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\ du\\
&\stackrel{z\leftarrow (x-u)/\sigma}{=} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} \left[f(x-\sigma z) - f(x)\right]\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\ dz
\end{align*}$$

So now let $f$ be the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) on $[0,1]$, and $0$ everywhere else, i.e.
$$f(x) := \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q\\
0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

It is clear that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb R$, however for any $x\in\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$, and any sequence of rationals $(\sigma_n)$ which converges to $0$, such as $\sigma_n \equiv \frac1n$, we have

$$\begin{align*}f_{\sigma_n}(x) - f(x) = f_{\sigma_n}(x) &= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x-\sigma_n z) \exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\ dz\\
&= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q}f(x-\sigma_n z)\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\ dz\\
&= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(x-1)/\sigma_n}^{x/\sigma_n}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)\ dz \\
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow} -1\ne 0\end{align*}$$

Where we used the properties of the Lebesgue integral and the fact that if $z$ is irrational, then $x-\sigma z$ is irrational for any rational $x$ and rational $\sigma\ne 0$. By scaling and shifting, we thus see that it's possible to produce similar counter-examples for any subset of the form $\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]$.

---

This example shows that the author's claim can at best be true in the almost everywhere sense.  I actually suspect that if we only require integrability, pointwise convergence also fails on positive measure subsets, but I haven't found such an example yet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, as you noted, and I have explicitly written in my post, what I'm asking is about almost sure pointwise convergence.

Comment: Sure, I guess the point was to (hopefully) give a lead towards a negative example on a positive measure set.